# CURL Request to Laravel API Returns NULL Values

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I'm attempting to send an array of objects as part of a JSON request with curl.  The request must use `json_encode` in order to be sent by curl. However I am running into an issue on the Laravel API that is receiving it. Any attempt to get an object from the Request Laravel object returns null i.e.:

```
$request->order_number;
$request->items;
```

This is the case for normal fields and the array of objects I am also sending.  The curl appears as:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($request));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Accept: application/json'
));
```

What is the mistake I am making?

EDIT:
To provide more specific information, here is the `json_encode` var dumped (some omissions):

> string(694) "{"order_number":"11111","items":"[{"id":"1005","name":"UpRight 011238-004 Washer, Split Lock","sku":"","quantity":1,"price":0.01}]"}"

Comment: What is the value of `json_encode($request)` in/around your cURL code? Output it and make sure it contains what you expect.

Comment: It contains exactly what i expect with the order number and other fields along with the array of objects. I have edited my question with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being rather convoluted:

```
public function postOrderInformation(Request $data) {
        $request = json_decode(json_encode(json_decode($data->getContent(), true)));
}
```

This created a useable object from which the data could be extracted from the laravel Requets object.  If anyone has a more elegant/less ugly solution, please post it.